# react testing library props test passed without props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tdd, react-testing-library

I'm tried to practice TDD with react and react testing library.

So, I have some basic button component and test for it. I'll have in this component some prop like id and name.

Here is before define props to the component I tried to write some test to control my props they have in my component or not.

```
const defaultProps = {
  dataTestId: "button-id",
  text: "Button Text",
};

test("component takes own props", () => {
  render(<Button {...defaultProps} />);
});
```

and here my empty component:

```
export const Button = () => {
  return <div></div>;
};
```

I don't have any props in my component. Here I expect that test will fail. But the test passed.

What's wrong?

Comment: Why would the test fail? JavaScript doesn't really care about function arity, you're just passing an argument that gets ignored, and you have no expectations to go unmet.

Comment: I think that test should be failed. And It's normal that you don't have these props in the component. Otherwise, you will need to write the first component then test. So it's not TDD. I think that my test code is not ok. And actually, I wanted to ask about this. Maybe need to make another implementation.

Comment: But you haven't written a test that the button *does* anything, there's no *behaviour* for it to fail to provide. All you're testing is whether the function accepts an argument and returns an element or null, which it does.

Comment: O yep, I understood actually I need to add to my test logic extra control what will control each prop rendered this content or have in a document or not. Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: I wrote a blog post on test-driving React that might be useful: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Nov/22/js-tdd-e2e.html

Comment: Thanks it will be very useful for me now :)   const { getByText } = render(<Button {...defaultProps} />);
    expect(getByText("Button Text")).toBeInTheDocument();  I have edited my test like this. And everyting worked well now.

Answer (score 0):

The test does not fails since, even if your components does not expect any props, JavaScript allows you to call a function (your component, in this case) by passing parameters that are not expected by the function itself.

Take a look to this example:

```
const example = () => console.log("This is a test");
example("useless parameter");
```

This is a valid JavaScript code.

Comment: Yep, I got it that there are no expected props in my component. But it's a TDD. I need to write a test first which will be failed then need to add these props.  I think here I use react-testing-library wrongly. And my question exactly about that.

Answer (score -1):

React doesn't care if you pass extra props to a function as they will just be unused variables which, although not best practice, is perfectly valid in JavaScript. You would notice the exact same behavior if you passed extra arguments to a function like this:

```js
function add(a, b) {
}

add(1, 2, 3)
```

Even though the `add` function uses the first two arguments, it is not an error to pass more than two arguments.